# Firebase update method produces Promise Rejection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm making an update request on my React Native app to my Firebase with redux in mind.

Here's my redux snippet

```
export function buyTicket(eventID) {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/Users/${currentUser.uid}/joinedEvent`).update({ [eventID]: true })
      .then(() => dispatch({ type: BUY_TICKET_SUCCESS }))
      .catch(() => dispatch({ type: BUY_TICKET_FAIL }));
  };
};
```

When the buyTicket function gets called, only the then() method should be expected but both then() and catch() got called.

According to the Firebase docs, update() produces a promise but its optional.

Here's the error I'm getting
[image: Error]

This is my reducer

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PULL_EVENT_DATA:
      return action.payload;
    case PULL_TRENDING_DATA:
      return action.payload;
    case BUY_TICKET_SUCCESS:
      return {
        message: 'Yay, see you there!'
      }
    case BUY_TICKET_FAIL:
      return {
        message: 'shit'
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Perhaps the console log might gives a clue?
[image]

Comment: are you sure that the catch returns? `Object.assign` is the first warning line, perhaps it has something to do with your reducer?

Comment: I have revised my reducer but it looks fine to me though... @Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jan pointed out the part I was missing, I was able to relocate the error and make it right.

The error I was making is mutability. I did not consider the concept of mutability when making the app, hence the error.

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PULL_EVENT_DATA:
      return action.payload;
    case PULL_TRENDING_DATA:
      return action.payload;
    case BUY_TICKET_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, message: action.payload}
    case BUY_TICKET_FAIL:
      return { ...state, message: action.payload}
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You may find more about mutability [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html#using-object-spread-operator)